# Radgridview show blank data when the column header contain bracket "[]"

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

When the data column header contains bracket"[]", the radgridview shows the empty cell even there is a data in here. 
There is a data in the cell and I can see the data when I open the filter. 
Does anybody know the reason?  Thanks
[image]

Comment: As i see on their forum, brackets was using for property binding, maybe because of that.